# Getting multible variables in Python in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I made [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/150109/multiple-numbers-calculator) calculator using Python and I'm happy with it(considering it's my very first Python program). The only thing I would like to improve is the input system.
This is my current way of getting the variables, but I have to enter each variable with a space between, like this: 2 + 3 * 4. What I would like to be able to do is to enter them without a space, like this: 2+3*4.

In C++ you can do:

```
std::cin >> num1 >> act1 >> num2 >> act2 >> num3;
```

My question is if there is a way to do the same thing in Python?

This is the code I'm using now to get the variables:

```
user_input=input("Enter a num1 act1 num2 act2 num3 (with a space between them): ")      #Gets the values
var1, action1, var2, action2, var3=user_input.split()           #assigns the values into the variables
```

Comment: You could read in a string and then parse it yourself - unless you will always have very constrained input - which doesn't make for a very flexible calculator :)

Comment: you have to check char-by-char and recognize digits to create number, and recognize other chars to get `+*`. Or use [PLY - Python Lex-Yacc](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) to build real parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into the regular expression `re` module to parse the user input:

```
import re

user_input = input(...)

pattern = '(?P<num1>\d+)\s?(?P<act1>.)\s?(?P<num2>\d+)\s?(?P<act2>.)\s?(?P<num3>\d+)'
res = re.search(pattern, user_input)

your_first_number = res.group('num1')
your_first_action = res.group('act1')
# etc.
```

- Each number (with 1 or more digits) is represented by `(?P<num1>\d+)`, which is a `re` group I named `num1`.
- The operator is represented in a similar fashion, where `.` is any single character, or an operator in this case.
- There may be 0 or 1 spaces between each number and operator, which is represented by `\s?`.
- And I repeat this pattern.

`re` makes it a little more complicated, but it's more flexible in terms how the user can type in his input.

Comment: when I do what it gives me the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Comment: @Sela12 - oops, I had a misplaced `<` in my first group. It shoudn't give you an error anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
user_input = '2+12*9'

numbers = ''.join([x if x.isnumeric() else ' ' for x in user_input])
operators = [x for x in user_input if not x.isnumeric()]

var1, var2, var3 = numbers.rsplit(' ')
action1, action2 = operators[0], operators[1]
```

Basically using list comprehension to separate out the numbers and then the operators, and then using `rsplit` to assign the numbers to their variables and assigning the operator variables by their index in the list. This method will also allow you to use numbers with multiple digits.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `eval`, since this can calculate expressions for you.

However `eval` can be dangerous with untrusted input since by default it exposes the whole Python interpreter. This is not an issue for a program you use yourself, but could be problematic for say a module used in a web application.

In the example below (in [IPython](https://ipython.org/)), I've tried to make it less dangerous by using the `locals` and `globals` options. The `_locals` dict is used to make some functions from the `math` module available for use in expressions. The `_globals` dict disables Python's built-ins. Also note that this is in Python 3 which uses floating point division for the `/` operator.

```
In [1]: import math

In [2]: _globals = {"__builtins__": None}

In [3]: _lnames = ('acos', 'asin', 'atan', 'ceil', 'cos', 'cosh', 'e', 'log', 'log10',
   ...:            'pi', 'sin', 'sinh', 'sqrt', 'tan', 'tanh')

In [4]: _locals = {k: eval('math.'+k) for k in _lnames}

In [5]: eval('2+3*4', _globals, _locals)
Out[5]: 14

In [6]: eval('1+2/3', _globals, _locals)
Out[6]: 1.667

In [7]: eval('sin(pi)', _globals, _locals)
Out[7]: 1.225e-16

In [8]: eval('cos(pi)', _globals, _locals)
Out[8]: -1

In [9]: eval('cos(pi/2)', _globals, _locals)
Out[9]: 6.123e-17
```

Note that the outputs of 7 and 9 (which should be 0) are caused by the limits on accuracy of floating point arithmatic.

Comment: But how do I get the input?

Comment: @Sela12 Using the built-in function `input`.